# TS Type Definition Specify Location

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want TS to use all the .d.ts files in @types/ directory and also to consider .d.ts files that are located at specific places like ../library/library.d.ts

Can I do this in the tsconfig.json file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `typeRoots` compiler option within your tsconfig.json to do this. However, this will disable the default inclusion of visible @types packages so you will need to manually add it to `typeRoots` as well.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./path/to/my/type/directory",
            "./other/path/to/type/dir",
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

This is assuming that your tsconfig.json file is in the same directory level as node_modules. You'll need to change the `./node_modules/@types` relative path specified in `typeRoots` otherwise.